# Python - sorted expected 1 argument, got 3 - Trying to understand named arguments

Tags: python, arguments

I was looking into the `sorted()` function in Python 3.9 with the following tiny example

```
circus = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),('w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a'),('k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'),('u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y'),('q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u'),('e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i')]
```

It's just a list of quintuples that I want to sort by the fifth elements (i.e. the e, a, o, y, u, i)

I know the correct way to do this is

```
sorted(circus, key = lambda d: d[4], reverse = True)
```

But I was trying this

```
sorted(circus, lambda z: z[4], True)
```

and got the error

```
TypeError: sorted expected 1 argument, got 3
```

I'm trying to understand why it's expecting 1 argument. According to the documentation (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp), the other two are optional parameters, but they should still be expected, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the signature for `sorted` (`help(sorted)`)

```
sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)
```

you'll see the iterable parameter is positional only, while the other two are keyword-only. You can't use a keyword argument like `iterable=[1,2,3]` to provide the iterable to sort, and as you've seen, you can't specify the key function or the reverse flag using positional arguments.

The syntax for parameter definitions can be found in the [documentation for the `def` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> Parameters after “`*`” or “`*identifier`” are keyword-only parameters and may only be passed by keyword arguments. Parameters before “`/`” are positional-only parameters and may only be passed by positional arguments.

Comment: what is "/" and "*" here? and how do I know they are keyword only after looking at this?

Comment: Parameters before `/` are positional-only. Parameter between `/` and `*` are "regular" parameters (the kind you see in a simple definition like `def foo(x, y)`, which can be set by positional or keyword arguments). Parameters after `*` are keyword-only.